# SQL Like search in LIST and LINQ in C#

Tags: c#, linq

I have a List which contains the list of words that needs to be excluded.

My approach is to have a List which contains these words and use Linq to search.

```
List<string> lstExcludeLibs = new List<string>() { "CONFIG", "BOARDSUPPORTPACKAGE", "COMMONINTERFACE", ".H", };
string strSearch = "BoardSupportPackageSamsung";
bool has = lstExcludeLibs.Any(cus => lstExcludeLibs.Contains(strSearch.ToUpper()));
```

I want to find out part of the string strSearch is present in the lstExcludedLibs.

It turns out that `.any` looks only for exact match. Is there any possibilities of using like or wildcard search

Is this possible in linq?

I could have achieved it using a foreach and contains but I wanted to use LINQ to make it simpler.

Edit: I tried List.Contains but it also doesn't seem to work

Comment: Just an observation but, IMHO, your variable name prefixes 'lst' and 'str' should be ommitted. This is a mis-interpretation of Hungarian notation and is redundant.

Comment: have added the comment to my answer below

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You've got it the wrong way round, it should be:-

```
List<string> lstExcludeLibs = new List<string>() { "CONFIG", "BOARDSUPPORTPACKAGE", "COMMONINTERFACE", ".H", };
string strSearch = "BoardSupportPackageSamsung";
bool has = lstExcludeLibs.Any(cus => strSearch.ToUpper().Contains(cus));
```

Btw - this is just an observation but, IMHO, your variable name prefixes 'lst' and 'str' should be ommitted. This is a mis-interpretation of Hungarian notation and is redundant.

Answer (score 1):

I think the line should be:

```
bool has = lstExcludeLibs.Any(cus => cus.Contains(strSearch.ToUpper()));
```

Comment: With my example, i always get false with your suggestion. i am searching if `BoardSupportPackage` in `BoardSupportPackageSamsung`. Generally Contains should work, but i get false

Comment: Try changing it: bool has = lstExcludeLibs.Any(cus => strSearch.ToUpper().Contains(cus));

Comment: `ToUpper` and `ToLower` are common tricks, but a bad idea if you ever want to support any language but English.  See this question for a better solution than `ToUpper`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/444798/case-insensitive-containsstring

Comment: Nitpicking.Example code fails under Turkish locale. Uppercase of Config is CONFİG and therefore it does not match. Using `ToUpperInvariant()` is a better choice.

Answer (score 1):

Is this useful to you ?

```
bool has = lstExcludeLibs.Any(cus => strSearch.ToUpper().Contains(cus));
```

OR

```
bool has = lstExcludeLibs.Where(cus => strSearch.ToUpper().IndexOf(cus) > -1).Count() > 0;
```

OR

```
bool has = lstExcludeLibs.Count(cus => strSearch.ToUpper().IndexOf(cus) > -1) > 0;
```